# Show that $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty} P_k (x^{(i)} )$ exists but $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty} x^{(i)} $ does not

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $X=\{\{x_n\}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|<\infty\}$ be the vector space consisting of all real-valued sequences that are absolutely summing. Define \begin{align}P_k:X\to \Bbb{R}\end{align}
\begin{align}\{x_n\}\mapsto P_k(\{x_n\})=x_k,\;\;\forall \,k\in \Bbb{N}\end{align}
I want to construct a sequence of elements
in $X$ such that $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty} P_k (x^{(i)} )$ exists for all $k \in\Bbb{N}$, but such that the sequence $\{x^{(i)}\}$ itself fails to be a Cauchy sequence. The norm on $X$ is given by $\Vert \{x_n\}\Vert=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$.

**MY THOUGHT**

I'm thinking of $x^{(i)}=\frac{(-1)^i}{i},\;\forall \,i\in \Bbb{N}$. Am I right?

Comment: $(-1)^i/i$ is not an element of $X$, so that can't be right. Perhaps you should change your notation to make it clearer what symbols denote real numbers and what symbols denote elements of $X$ (that is, sequences of real numbers). The question is asking you to construct a *sequence of sequences of real numbers* such that the $k$th elements of the sequences converge for any fixed $k$, but that the entire sequence of elements of $X$ is not Cauchy. What metric are you using on $X$?—you need a metric (or a topology) here to define "Cauchy sequence".

Comment: @Greg Martin: I made some edits!

Comment: How about $x_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ where the $1$ is in the $i$th position?

Comment: Instead of writing $x_i$ for the element of $X$, you should write $x^{(i)}$

Comment: @mathworker21: Alright, noted!

Comment: @Sven Pistre: Thanks a lot but how does $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}P_k(x^{(i)})$ exist?

Comment: @Mike For any fixed $k$, $P_k(x^{(i)}) = 0$ for large $i$

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your notation correctly. Isn't $P_k$ the projection onto the $k$th component of the sequence? Then $P_k(x^{(i)})=\delta_k^i$. So for fixed $k$, $\lim_{i\to\infty}P_k(x^{(i)})=0$.

Comment: @Sven Pistre: Thanks very much but what is $\delta_k^{i}$. Sorry that I seem ignorant!

Comment: This is the notation for the Kronecker delta, i.e. $\delta_k^i=0$ if $k\neq i$ and $\delta_k^i=1$ if $k=i$.

Comment: @Sven Pistre: Thanks, got it now!

Comment: @Sven Pistre: There is a little confusion here! Please, how does $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}x_i$ fail to exist?

Comment: @Mike what do you think the limit should be?

Comment: @mathworker21: Can I use the fact that $\dim x_i=\infty$?